# Count multiple columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am having hard time writing the query that counts occurrence of specific value in multiple columns. I cannot change the structure of db. I know I can do this using multiple queries and union at the end, but I was wondering is there any smarter solution.

Here is an example.
   

+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+

| A            | B            |
C            |
D            |

+-----------+------------+------------+------------+

| value1   | value2    | value1    | value3    |

| value2   | value3    | value1    | value4    |

| value1   | value3    | value2    | value1    |

| value3   | value1    | value1    | value1    |

| value1   | value1    | value1    | value1    |

+-----------+------------+------------+------------+

I would like to count number of fields where value=value1 for each column. A result set should look like this:

+-----------+------------+

| Column  | Count     |

+-----------+------------+

| A            | 3            | 

| B            | 2            | 

| C            | 4            | 

| D            | 3            | 

+-----------+------------+

Thanks

Comment: I have tried with union, to make count for every column in separate query and then to create union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it on a single row similar to Anirudh's response try this:

```
SELECT SUM(A='Value1'),
    SUM(B='Value1'),
    SUM(C='Value1'),
    SUM(D='Value1')
FROM TableName
```

Alternatively to have it the way you specified you can use this:

```
SELECT 'A', SUM(A='Value1')
FROM TableName
UNION
SELECT 'B', SUM(B='Value1')
FROM TableName
UNION
SELECT 'C', SUM(C='Value1')
FROM TableName
UNION
SELECT 'D', SUM(D='Value1')
FROM TableName
```

Edit: SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a99a/6

Comment: This solves my problem. I was so focused on how to get one row for each column, that I didn't take this into consideration at all. I can handle this in code quite easy. It is very simple and elegant approach. Thanks. –

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using horizontal aggreagation

```
`SELECT sum(case when A=value1 then 1 else 0 END) as CountValue1,sum(case when A=value2 then 1 else 0 END) as CountValue2,sum(case when A=value3 then 1 else 0 END) as CountValue3   FROM tableName;`
```

by this you can convert rows into column but not column into rows