# Count multiple columns in a query for multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, aggregate

I have a query that should count the number of items used by department.

The first two tables give me the units and the persons who used the items.

The third table tells who used what.

**STAFF(EMPID,EMPNAME,UNITCTR)**

**CAFUNIT(UNITCTR, UNITDSC)**

**CAFTRXHD(BILLNO,TRXDATE,ITEMCODE,ITEMPRICE,ITEMDESC,ITEMPRICE,EMPID)**

This is the query

```
SELECT a.UNITCTR, b.UNITDSC, COUNT(c.ITEMCODE)
FROM UNIT.STAFF a, UNIT.CAFUNIT b, UNIT.CAFTRXHID c
WHERE a.UNITCTR = b.UNITCTR  
  AND c.ITEMCODE IN ('397', '398', '399', '400', '401', '402', '403')
GROUP BY a.UNITCTR, b.UNITDSC
```

This returns the count of all used items by department for example Department A used 200 of these items, so I get the Department ID, name and the total count of items.

```
123|Cafeteria|200
```

where 200 is the sum of all of these items (397 to 403)

I need to know the count for each item by department for instance Department A used 10 boxes of item 397 and 5 of item B and …

```
123|Cafeteria|20|20|50|30|50|10|70
```

Using what is [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799688/count-multiple-columns-mysql) isn't working or I am not doing it right. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results - its very hard to know what you want based on a non-working query and a text description.

Comment: Try to put `c.ITEMCODE` in Group by also.

Comment: Also, please don't use old-style comma joins, use proper explicit joins.

Comment: Open to all suggestion, newbie in SQL.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: You need to show the raw sample data that you are querying, for example, I can't tell which column is the department column, nor how it fits with the rest of the data. You need to provide a [mre] - one way to do that is create a DBFiddle which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: You need ItemCodes as columns not Rows ?

Comment: There are many departments but only these items, so my idea is a column containing all the departments and a row for these items.

Comment: SELECT sum(case when A=value1 then 1 else 0 END) as total
Try like this @user10191234

Answer (score 1):

Hello after checking you request, follows a query what I think could help you, I'm using two queries with partition, one to group all items by unit and another to group items by unit and item code.

```
WITH STAFF  AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, 'John Smith','U1'), 
        (2, 'David Thompson','U2'), 
        (3, 'Stacey Leigh','U3')
    ) AS _ (EMPID,EMPNAME,UNITCTR)
),CAFUNIT  AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        ('U1', 'Unit 1'), 
        ('U2', 'Unit 2'), 
        ('U3', 'Unit 3')
    ) AS _ (UNITCTR,UNITDSC)
),CAFTRXHD as (
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, '2022-01-01','item 1',100,'Item desc 1',1), 
        (2, '2022-02-01','item 2',200,'Item desc 2',2),
        (3, '2022-03-01','item 3',300,'Item desc 3',3),
        (4, '2022-01-01','item 1',100,'Item desc 1',1),
        (5, '2022-01-01','item 2',100,'Item desc 2',1),
        (6, '2022-01-01','item 2',100,'Item desc 2',1),
        (7, '2022-02-01','item 2',200,'Item desc 2',2),
        (8, '2022-02-01','item 2',200,'Item desc 2',2),
        (9, '2022-03-01','item 3',300,'Item desc 3',3),
        (10, '2022-03-01','item 3',300,'Item desc 3',3),
        (11, '2022-03-01','item 3',300,'Item desc 3',3)
    ) AS _ (BILLNO,TRXDATE,ITEMCODE,ITEMPRICE,ITEMDESC,EMPID)
),
--Get all item group by Unit
GetAllByUnit as (
    SELECT 
    t.* FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        IT.UNITCTR,
        IT.UNITDSC,
        (SUM(ITEMPRICE) OVER (partition by IT.UNITCTR order by IT.UNITDSC)) as TotalValue
    FROM 
        CAFTRXHD as HD
        INNER JOIN STAFF as FF ON HD.EMPID = FF.EMPID
        INNER JOIN CAFUNIT as IT ON FF.UNITCTR = IT.UNITCTR
    ) as t
    GROUP BY t.UNITCTR, T.UNITDSC, T.TotalValue
),
--Get all item group by Unit and Item code
GetAllByUnitAndCode as (
    SELECT 
    t.* FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        IT.UNITCTR,
        IT.UNITDSC,
        HD.ITEMCODE,
        (SUM(ITEMPRICE) OVER (partition by IT.UNITCTR,HD.ITEMCODE order by IT.UNITDSC)) as TotalValue
    FROM 
        CAFTRXHD as HD
        INNER JOIN STAFF as FF ON HD.EMPID = FF.EMPID
        INNER JOIN CAFUNIT as IT ON FF.UNITCTR = IT.UNITCTR
    ) as t
    GROUP BY t.UNITCTR, T.UNITDSC, T.ITEMCODE, T.TotalValue
)
SELECT * FROM GetAllByUnit
--SELECT * FROM GetAllByUnitAndCode
```

The result

```
UNITCTR  UNITDSC        TotalValue
U1       Unit 1     400
U2       Unit 2     600
U3       Unit 3     1200
```

Comment the query last line --SELECT * FROM GetAllByUnit and remove the comment over SELECT * FROM GetAllByUnitAndCode

```
    --SELECT * FROM GetAllByUnit
    SELECT * FROM GetAllByUnitAndCode
```

The result here is top down not only one line

```
UNITCTR UNITDSC     ITEMCODE    TotalValue
U1      Unit 1      item 1      200
U1      Unit 1      item 2      200
U2      Unit 2      item 2      600
U3      Unit 3      item 3      1200
```

Best Regards